# Why can't I call the create method of FakeSplitInstallManagerFactory that only requires Context to be passed?

Tags: android, android-instant-apps, android-module, google-play-core

The new `FakeSplitInstallManagerFactory` has a `create` method that takes `Context` however when I try to use it from my code I only get the method that takes `Context` and a `File` which is a directory. If I tell AS to show me the definition of the class, I can see both `create` methods. They are both `public` and they are both `static`, yet only one can be called from my code. I've tried cleaning, running gradle again, etc. I don't understand what the issue might be?

This is the error I get:

[image]

This is what I get on auto complete:

[image]

If I press `control+b` I get:

```
package com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.testing;

import com.google.android.play.core.splitcompat.SplitCompat;
import com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallManager;
import android.content.Context;

/** Creates instances of {@link com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.testing.FakeSplitInstallManager FakeSplitInstallManager}. */

@SuppressWarnings({"unchecked", "deprecation", "all"})
public class FakeSplitInstallManagerFactory {

public FakeSplitInstallManagerFactory() { throw new RuntimeException("Stub!"); }

/**
 * Creates a fake implementation of the {@link com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.SplitInstallManager SplitInstallManager}.
 *
 * <p>This implementation is self-contained and obtains splits from a specified directory, which
 * can be populated passing the --local-testing flag to bundletool build-apks and using bundletool
 * install-apks to install the app.
 *
 * <p>It is provided for testing, e.g. checking sequences of events when installing dynamic
 * features and additional languages. It is suitable for use in integration tests.
 *
 * <p>This fake supports just one install request at a time.
 *
 * <p>Network errors can be simulated using {@link com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.testing.FakeSplitInstallManager#setShouldNetworkError(boolean) FakeSplitInstallManager#setShouldNetworkError(boolean)}.
 *
 * <p>{@link com.google.android.play.core.splitcompat.SplitCompat SplitCompat} must be installed appropriately to use this class.
 *
 * <p>This method will always return the same {@link com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.testing.FakeSplitInstallManager FakeSplitInstallManager} instance.
 */

public static com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.testing.FakeSplitInstallManager create(android.content.Context context) { throw new RuntimeException("Stub!"); }

/**
 * Alternative version of {@link #create(android.content.Context)} which allows for the splits directory to be set
 * explicitly.
 *
 * <p>The constructor receives the directory on the device where the split apks can be obtained.
 * The file name format is the same as the extracted output of bundletool build-apks. The apks in
 * the directory must be signed by the same certificate as the app. If this directory is missing,
 * install requests will fail with {@link
 * com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.model.SplitInstallErrorCode#API_NOT_AVAILABLE}.
 *
 * <p>In general, all configuration splits for the module that are present in the folder will be
 * included. Thus, consider pre-filtering them for the device - e.g. using appropriate bundletool
 * build-apks argument. However, since languages can change over time on the device, there will be
 * additional filtering of language splits, whereby only appropriate languages will be included.
 *
 * <p>Prefer using {@link #create(android.content.Context)} and let bundletool populate the default directory,
 * unless there's a good reason to use a different directory or filter the delivered APKs by hand.
 *
 * <p>This method will always return the same {@link com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.testing.FakeSplitInstallManager FakeSplitInstallManager} instance. It will
 * fail if called twice with different directories.
 */

public static synchronized com.google.android.play.core.splitinstall.testing.FakeSplitInstallManager create(android.content.Context context, java.io.File modulesDirectory) { throw new RuntimeException("Stub!"); }
}
```

Which clearly shows two `create` methods.

I am using the play core library `1.6.5` and this is a new clear project with nothing else. Right now I created a new clean project from a template, then added `implementation "com.google.android.play:core:1.6.5"` and it has the exact same issue. So what am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it's odd, but when you inspect `FakeSplitInstallManagerFactory.class` from the `com.google.android.play:core` AAR, for whatever reason, it looks like they left it out? That's why it won't let you use `create(context)`.

```
public class FakeSplitInstallManagerFactory {
    private static FakeSplitInstallManager a = null;

    public FakeSplitInstallManagerFactory() {
    }

    public static synchronized FakeSplitInstallManager create(Context var0, File var1) {
        if (a == null) {
            try {
                a = new FakeSplitInstallManager(var0, var1);
            } catch (Exception var3) {
                throw new RuntimeException(var3);
            }
        } else if (!a.a().getAbsolutePath().equals(var1.getAbsolutePath())) {
            throw new RuntimeException(String.format("Different module directories used to initialize FakeSplitInstallManager: '%s' and '%s'", a.a().getAbsolutePath(), var1.getAbsolutePath()));
        }

        return a;
    }
}
```

Maybe they will add it in later, since the docs, [Locally test module installs: Simulate a network error](https://developer.android.com/guide/playcore/testing-fakesplitinstallmanager#FakeSplitInstallManager) mentions the missing method (or maybe they're deprecating it in favor of `create(context, file)` but just haven't updated the docs), we'll see...

But here is a recent [medium/An easy way to test offline dynamic delivery](https://medium.com/@star_zero/an-easy-way-to-test-offline-dynamic-delivery-9b6909b62bcb) that talks about how to use `create(context, file)`

Comment: That sucks. So what path should I use?

Comment: Have you had a chance to read https://medium.com/@star_zero/an-easy-way-to-test-offline-dynamic-delivery-9b6909b62bcb yet? Shows you how to use it.

Comment: Yeah I had seen that but I had assumed there was going to be a AS way of doing it, without bundletool. Just seems really painful for testing. Thanks.

Comment: According to Google `1.7.1` fixes this. Haven't tried it yet.